# Confusion about electromotive force and Kirchhoff's voltage law

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

I know that an electromotive force is necessarily non-electrostatic; however, it's always invoked in Kirchhoff's voltage law in textbooks without justification. Can someone explain to me why? Especially in a simple circuit containing a battery and a resistor, even though the EMF is most probably chemical.

Comment: Can you give an example of the textbook passages you are confused about, and the exact nature of that confusion?  As stated, your question is not specific enough to give an answer.

Comment: The battery's process is electrochemical, but the forces exerted by the ions and the charges involved are electrostatic (well, electromagnetic. You didn't use the term electrostatic properly because a circuit with current flowing does not have static charges just sitting there. There's no such thing as an electrochemical force as far as I know.

Comment: Why can I include the electromotive force of a battery ,connected to an external resistance, in Kirschoff's law? is it equal to the potential difference across the battery? or is it the electromotive force itself intended when applying kirschhoff's law? What's going on?